# Open html on defined id

Tags: html

I´m tryin` to start a html-file always on a defined id.

I know that´s possible if you use that:

```
<a href="index2.html#id">go to...</a>
```

But this happens only if this link was clicked.
How can i force it all the time?

Comment: What "id" do you mean? As hard as I try I can't understand what exactly you want to achieve. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I´m sorry, the code wasn´t complete. I mean, i have two html-files: index and index2. i want that always if index2 is open, it starts at the "id"-anchor.

Answer (score 0):

To start on a defined anchor (hash-defined) you will need to use JavaScript. The hash anchor in the end of a URL is used by the browser just after the navigation completes and you can't force it to "auto"-move without any client-side code.

To achieve similar effect with javascript perform the following function when the page is loaded:

```
function jumpToId( id ){
  location.hash = "#" + id;
}
```

Of course, you will need to supply the id you want to jump to as the parameter to this function.

Please note, that in case JavaScript is disabled in the client's browser, the scrolling will not be performed. It is not a big deal, however, because majority of users have JavaScript enabled all the time (especially in today's social network-driven world :-) ).

Answer (score 0):

Do you want it to scroll to the area or just immediately pop the user to it? For scroll you could use jQuery and just set it to scroll to the div using `$(document).ready()`.

Here is an example. If you just want them to pop to it you could change the `1000` to `1` and it appears to immediately pop to the div.

[Example Here Using jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/sFrUx/1/)

---